# C# - Skype Auto Accept Contact Request

Tags: c#, bots, skype

So I'm currently working on a Skype bot thing, I wish it could automatically accept contact request so I don't have to do them manually, any idea how?

And while I was researching, I found this

```
ichat.AcceptAdd();
```

Any idea what does that do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood what you want to accomplish..

Do you want to accept contact requests automatically? Really? Do you like being target for hackers, spammers, etc? :)

Anyway, if that's what you want to do, you can subscribe to the UserAuthorizationRequestReceived event:

```
var events = (_ISkypeEvents_Event) _skype;
events.UserAuthorizationRequestReceived += UserAuthorizationRequestReceived;
try
{
    _skype.Attach(8);
}
catch(COMException ce)
{
    RaiseErrorEvent("Unable to attach to skype.", ce);
}


private void UserAuthorizationRequestReceived(SKYPE4COMLib.User puser)
{
     if (do some user check here?? )
     {
         puser.IsAuthorized = true;
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, and well I don't really care much since it's just a bot that I made for fun with friends. :P